# Jupyter Lab in Anaconda not working :Error executing Jupyter command 'lab': [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[image: this is the only error i get]I have installed jupyter lab in anaconda using "conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab" in the anaconda command prompt, but when i try to launch jupyter lab the error mentioned above comes up.

P.S I am able to open Jupyter Notebook through anaconda.

Comment: Do you get a full traceback? If so, post it here in full please, the error itself doesn't say much.

Comment: @GPhilo I added an image to my post which is the only error i get

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Anaconda Navigator closed, right click on Anaconda Navigator and click "Run As Administrator"

Then, when you launch JupyterLab it will work.

Comment: I'd hoped for a solution that doesn't give Jupyter Lab too much authority, but this works.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have full admin permissions on your machine, one workaround would be to replicate the jupyter-notebook shortcut, but point it to jupyter-lab instead.

To do that:

- Find the jupyter-notebook shortcut (on Win10 in `C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)`)
- Make a copy of the Jupyter Notebook shortcut, rename it to Jupyter Lab
- Right click and open Properties and on the last line where it says `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"` change `jupyter-notebook-script.py` to `jupyter-lab-script.py`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!